# Using Steam Web API from an Android app

Tags: java, android, steam-web-api, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to add some information from Steam into my Android app. 
I see that Steam has [Steamworks](https://partner.steamgames.com/home/steamworks), but that is only built for Windows, OSX and Linux.

Furthermore, I saw that they also have a [Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) that could also be accessed from a mobile application. But all the methods in the API require a 64 bit SteamID, which they say can be retrieved using [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/). I downloaded the [Google Oauth Client Library for JAVA](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/) but I reading through the documentation, I don't understand how I can get a SteamID for a user using this library.

Has anyone used this lib or another open source lib to get a SteamID?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

To get direct SteamID64.

- Login to Steam using a web broswer.
- Once logged click on your profile and add ?xml=1 to browser url address

http://steamcommunity.com/id/yourusername/?xml=1 or

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/yourprofilenumber/?xml=1 (if you have not set a public username yet)

---

I think this is number in profile link or steamID64 example: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198113616635

Steamid will be: 76561198113616635

To check it online you can go to https://steamid.io/lookup

In Android app, I think after authorize, steam will give you that number and key.

Comment: I know how to get my SteamID, but I need to have a way to get the SteamID of a user that uses my app. He will not be able to give my that SteamID, so I want to use OpenID to get it from Steam.

Comment: Are you try to implement this app ? After login through steam what information you will get back from steam ?

Comment: I want to use their Web API(see link to it in the question) to get a list of friends and some other info. I only get access to that if I have the SteamID.

Comment: The first thing if you want get information from user, user must allow you to get through login with steam. After that, you will get SteamID, is this correct ?